# Create a validation for a managed lightning button on Salesforce Opportunity

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, validation, button

0

Hi I am struggling to build this in SF.

I have tried to create a validation for a managed lightning button (I cannot edit its functionality), on the opportunity level.

The scenario is:
If the user should click the button, while a specific text field on the opportunity level is empty, it should not allow the button to work.

I read [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246809/add-validation-to-managed-lightning-button) that I need to create a VF page, and an Apex class controller, but didn't really succeed doing this.

I tried building the controller as following:

public class ButtonValidationController {
if(String.isBlank(Opportunity.Billing_Street__c))
}

Can you give an actual example of the syntax I need to build?

Thank you.

Comment: Button is quick action on detail page of Opportunity?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Feels like a job for dynamic actions, but that rather depends on the managed package's action as to whether you can do this. As already mentioned, in comments, it isn't clear what the scenario actually is.

Comment: (Also dynamic actions are not available on all standard objects)